# How to troubleshooting Amazon S3 GET request signature mismatch?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I've successfully uploaded a file to Amazon S3 using a signed url request generated by Amazons Java library:

```
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest =
    new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucket, objectName)

generatePresignedUrlRequest.
    withContentType(contentType).
    withMethod(HTTPMethod.PUT)

URL url = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest)
```

I changed `HTTPMethod.PUT` to `HTTPMethod.GET` and called it with the same arguments.

When I paste the resulting URL into my browser, I get:

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
</Message>
<AWSAccessKeyId>XXXX</AWSAccessKeyId>
<StringToSign>GET 1449712291 /my-bucket/picture.png</StringToSign>
....
</Error>
```

Is there a way to pull the so-called `StringToSign` being used out of the presigned request object to compare?  Or is there another way to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
withContentType(contentType)
```

This line doesn't make sense.  You wouldn't set `Content-Type:` for a `GET` request, since that header describes what you're *sending* -- which is "nothing" for a typical `GET` request.  Since that is one of the components of the string to sign, and the error response shows that S3 wants it blank, removing this should solve the issue.

Comment: You sir...are a hero!

Comment: Thanks. Happy to help.  Feel free to send lucrative custom development & consulting projects my way. :)